# Android NDK building shared library - Aborting - stop. local_module_filename must not contain a file extension

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

Here is my *Android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES = -lboost_system ...
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := AVL
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libAVL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AVL.cpp    

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_55    

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

*Application.mk*

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

*Error:*

```
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk:AVL: LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME must not contain a file extension    
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-static-library.mk:29: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Any idea how to build shared library?
PP: Using eclipse.

Comment: Why do you have `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY) ` if you're building a shared library?

Comment: Removed it and now I'm getting
/home/manevbg/Documents/android-sdks/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/AVL/AVL.o: in function _GLOBAL__sub_I_AVL.cpp:jni/boost/include/boost-1_55/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:= libAVL`. The build system will correctly prefix the library with 'lib' for you.